# Creating a simple Mailing form in php

Tags: php, forms, email

Okay, so ive been trying to create a very simple order system in php, which consists of one page of diffrent form fields, which you fill in and submit, When submitted theres a verifcation page that will either send the mail, or declare an error. It worked perfectly for a week or so, then I made minor changes to the files and uploaded them, changed them back. Now it refuses to work. Here's my code for both pages:

```
</head>
<body>
    <form name="detaljer" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" 
          method="POST">
        <p>Ange önskad kaliber</p>
        <select name="kaliberCombo">
            <option value=".22">.22</option>
            <option value="9mm">9x19mm</option>
            <option value=".40">.40</option>
            <option value=".45">.45</option>
            <option value=".357">.357</option>
            </select>
        </br>
            <p>Declare number:</p>
            <input type="number" name="antal" min="100">
            <p>Name*:</p><input type="text" name="fnamn"><input type="text" name="enamn">
            <p>Email*:</p><input type="text" name="email">
            <p>Adress:</p><input type="text" name="address">
            <p>Phone*:</p><input type="text" name="telefon">
            <br>
            <p>Add a comment</p>
            <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="300">

            </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <br><p>* required fields</p>

    </form>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Theres also some jscript above it, although that should not matter.

And then theres the verification page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

$kaliber=$_POST['kaliberCombo'];
$antal = $_POST['antal'];
$fornamn = $_POST['fnamn'];
$efternamn = $_POST['enamn'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$kommentar = $_POST['comment'];        


$sender = "Anyname";
$sendername = "examplemail@example.com";
$recipient = "gbreisch@hotmail.com";
$recipientname = "gbreisch";
$subject = "Bestallning!";
$message = "Bestallning \n
$fornamn $efternamn har beställt    
\n'$antal'st $kaliber \n
Email: $mail\n
Telefon: $telefon\n
Kommentar som gavs av kund: $kommentar";


$date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
$mid = "<" . sha1(microtime()) . "@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ">";


mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");


$sendername = mb_encode_mimeheader($sendername);
$recipientname = mb_encode_mimeheader($recipientname);

$headers =<<<EOT
From: $sendername <$sender>
Date: $date
Message-ID: $mid
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
EOT;

$status = mb_send_mail("$recipientname <$recipient>", $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$sender");
if(!$status) {
        echo "Could not send your order.";
}
else {
        echo "Order sent!";
}?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's driving me insane since the code worked fine recently, and I have tried using an old copy, it refuses to send.

Comment: Try changing your `mb_send_mail` to just `mail` and see if that works. Other than that, I can't see why you're having a problem. Also try to test without the periods, for example your `value=".40"` etc. Your host might've changed some configurations without you knowing.

Comment: I ran into this earlier today actually, and I had yet to consider it, but I tried echo:ing out all of the variables on the next page, and that seemed to work, nevertheless, I tried removing the dots in all of the values, didn't matter...this is driving me mad.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump`? If so, what were the results?

Comment: I havn't tried that, mainly becuase im so new to php that I've yet to have heard about it, I'll look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should try to send an e-mail via your form and look into your spam folder, if webserver has blocked your mail.

Comment: I've tried picking out the email function on its own, but even that refuses to send email, and when I rewrote the if statement dealing with the send function, it worked, but no mail was actually sent...I dont know what other factors are at play here, thanks for the reply.